# MySQL Subquery Causing Server to Hang

Tags: mysql, in-subquery

I'm trying to execute the following query

```
SELECT * FROM person 
         WHERE id IN 
             ( SELECT user_id FROM participation 
                    WHERE activity_id = '1' AND application_id = '1' 
             )
```

The outer query returns about 4000 responses whilst the inner returns 29. When executed on my web server nothing happened and when I tested it locally mysql ended up using 100% CPU and still achieved nothing. Could the size be the cause?

Specifically it causes the server to hang forever, I'm fairly sure the web server I ran the query on is in the process of crashing due to it (woops).

Comment: It hangs for how long? A few seconds, a couple of minutes, forever?

Comment: put index on `id` of  table `person` and `user_id` of table `participation`

Comment: can we see DDL for the tables?

Comment: IN is/was notorious for being slow

Comment: @Zaki, IN is slow when compared to a proper join is possible on the same query. However, I wouldn't use the blanket statement that it's slow. It's great to use when you want records for a constantly defined list of ids.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use an inner join for this query? i think that would be faster (and easier to read) - and maybe it solves your problem (but i can't find a failure in your query).

**EDIT:** the inner-join-solution would look like this:

```
SELECT
  person.*
FROM
  person
INNER JOIN
  participation
ON
  person.id = participation.user_id
WHERE
  participation.activity_id = '1'
AND
  participation.application_id = '1'
```

Comment: Subquery is executed for each row of the main query, so JOIN is a proper and much faster approach.

Comment: @Naktibalda, are you sure? That wasn't my understanding of how a subquery worked. I am almost positive that a temporary table is created so it's only executed once.

Comment: Thanks oezi, I'll give it a go if/when the server comes up again haha.

Comment: Do not use or recommend the comma syntax. Use the proper ANSI INNER JOIN format.

Answer (score 1):

How many rows are there in `participation` table and what indexes are there? 
A multi-column index on (user_id, activity_id, application_id) could help here.

Re comments: IN isn't slow. Subqueries within IN can be slow, if they're correlated to outer query.